# what is happening when we use a json key as JS codes?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm from C++ and know very little about JavaScript.

In JavaScript, I know we can do following:

```
    <script>
    var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "gibberish":"New York"}');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name + ", " + obj.gibberish;
    </script>
```

This is an example from W3School. And certainly, the JSON Object could be get from anywhere. But I am very curious that what has happened when we use

```
    obj.name or obj.gibberish
```

How could Browser understand this names and gibberish? 
What is happening behind this? Is there any exceptions that we cannot use it this way?

thanks in advance

Comment: `obj` in your example is not a JSON object it is javascript object.

Comment: Can you mark one of the answers to appreciate the work they did to help you?

Comment: Thanks, Tribual, I didn't get much time on checking(hands on experiments) on your answer yet. so didn't mark the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `obj` is a JavaScript object and not a JSON object anymore, as stated by @zb. You can convert a JSON string, such as `'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "gibberish":"New York"}'` into a JS object using `JSON.parse`. This returns an object. In JavaScript every object has properties. As such properties are values associated with objects. The dot notiation in `obj.name` is essentially retrieving the value for the `name` property which is defined on `obj`. Same applies for `obj.gibberish`.

The browser knows how to handle objects and allows you to access properties using the dot notation. Another way of accessing a property defined on an object is to use the square bracket notation, e.g. `obj['name']`. It looks pretty much like working with an array but the difference here is that `obj` is an object and not an array. In addition, you don't pass in an index but rather the name of property (as a string) that you want to access.

What happens behind the scenes is that your code will be interpreted and the expression `obj.name` evaluates to `John` and `obj.gibberish` evaluates to `New York`.

As far as the `.innerHTML` is concerned, you are assigning it the values of both the `name` and `gibberish` property and concatenate it with a comma. In fact, `innerHTML` is yet another property defined on an object, in your case it's the native DOM element returned by `document.getElementById("demo")`. It lets you set the HTML content of that element. If we assume that the inner html of a`<p id="demo"></p>` element is empty and you call a function in which you reasign the value to `obj.name + ", " + obj.gibberish` then the HTML content of that element will look like this:

```
<p id="demo">John, New York</p>
```

You can see this in action [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_innerhtml).

And to answer your last question

> Is there any exceptions that we cannot use it this way?

No, whenever you are dealing with an object, you can use the dot or square bracket notation to access properties on an object. However, you run into problems when accessing a property of something that is `null` or `undefined`, for example

```
obj.address.street
```

Here `address` is `undefined` which results into the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined`. This does not apply to `obj.name.firstname`. Althogh `name` has no property called `firstname`, because it is a string, you won't get the same error. It will simply return `undefined`. You might think that you could create a property on a string. However, strings are one of JavaScript's primitive types along with `number`, `boolean`, `null` and `undefined`. Those primitive types **can't** have properties. There is only one non-primitive type: *Object* which **can** have properties.

The only exception to what I have said above about not having properties on primitive types is that if you use getters and setters. That means if you have a defined getter for a given property then you could create properties on primitive types. But that's a bit off topic and I would like to redirect you to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) where you can find more information on `set` and `get`.

Answer (score 2):

`'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "gibberish":"New York"}'` is a `JSON` string .You need to convert [Json Object](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiS9c3d04_UAhXLLo8KHS9KDCkQFggtMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FGuide%2FWorking_with_Objects&usg=AFQjCNHkWd0cPrnSwr70pbnvBWE5JqmVjw&sig2=2bfawmFxUedofU9khrd_SA)  using with [`JSON.parse`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDsLKR1I_UAhVLp48KHV9BDwAQFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse&usg=AFQjCNHkowMNeO8CgweprUJz3xDY9HxuPQ&sig2=JjH_U2hXTSq9kMw67NFLRQ).

After converted to Object It see like this

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":null,"age":30, "gibberish":"New York"}');
console.log(obj)
```

See the `console.log` [Object](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTnryX1Y_UAhVGto8KHUk4Cv8QFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FGuide%2FWorking_with_Objects&usg=AFQjCNHkWd0cPrnSwr70pbnvBWE5JqmVjw&sig2=5UeTsKHReLSzpbFJ2mWalA) have **key and value** pair .You have to get the specific value from object with respected key .

```js
    var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "gibberish":"New York"}');
   console.log(obj.name)
```

```
eg : obj.name
```

First get the whole `obj` data then get the specific value of the key represent `name` .This same process with all key value pair of the object `obj.gibberish`=>`New York`

Answer (score 0):

To access `JSON data` in Javascript we use `dot notation`. Lets take an example of object `obj` **:**

```
var obj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "gibberish":"New York"}
```

In order to access the properties, we will be using dot notation like this **:**

```
obj.name // John
obj.age // 30
obj.gibberish // New York
```

Here, The variable `obj` is first, followed by a dot, followed by the key to be accessed.

To print the values we can either use `alert()` or `console.log()` in JavaScript.

We can also use square bracket syntax to access property value from `JSON`. To access that we have to keep the key in double quotes within square brackets. Like this **:**

```
obj["name"] // John
obj["age"] // 30
obj["gibberish"] // New York
```